# xwd output - unknown header

Tags: linux, command-line, x11

The output I get from a capture of the file browser:

```
xwd -name "CVandXdo - File Browser" -out capture.xwd
```

Doesn't match the [specification defined for xwd files](http://www.fileformat.info/format/xwd/egff.htm).

I plan on parsing the output for an image recognition program. But I cannot localize the xwd header. I need to know where the pixels start and how many rows and columns there are.

Here is the beginning of the xwd file using a hex-editor. The xwd command has put another header before I think, but I'm unable to find its documentation. I assume there is one header from 0x00 to 0x7c, but the actual xwd format header doesn't appear to begin after it.

```
00000000: 0000 007c 0000 0007 0000 0002 0000 0018  ...|............
00000010: 0000 01f1 0000 01b5 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000020: 0000 0020 0000 0000 0000 0020 0000 0020  ... ....... ... 
00000030: 0000 07c4 0000 0004 00ff 0000 0000 ff00  ................
00000040: 0000 00ff 0000 0008 0000 0100 0000 0100  ................
00000050: 0000 01f1 0000 01b5 0000 055e 0000 007a  ...........^...z
00000060: 0000 0000 4356 616e 6458 646f 202d 2046  ....CVandXdo - F
00000070: 696c 6520 4272 6f77 7365 7200 0000 0000  ile Browser.....
00000080: 0000 0000 0000 0701 0001 0101 0101 0101  ................
```

This is the same file, after I opened it in GIMP and saved it again.

```
00000000: 0000 0064 0000 0007 0000 0002 0000 0018  ...d............
00000010: 0000 01f1 0000 01b5 0000 0000 0000 0001  ................
00000020: 0000 0020 0000 0001 0000 0020 0000 0018  ... ....... ....
00000030: 0000 05d4 0000 0005 00ff 0000 0000 ff00  ................
00000040: 0000 00ff 0000 0008 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000050: 0000 01f1 0000 01b5 0000 0040 0000 0040  ...........@...@
00000060: 0000 0000 edec ebed eceb edec ebed eceb  ................
```

Can someone find me this arcane xwd documentation, or perhaps its "output implementation", that explain its behaviour? All my google-searching have resulted in tutorials in how to take screenshots using xwd.

Comment: Does ImageMagick parse the file correctly? If so just use it to convert to whatever format your code prefers.

Comment: Yes it was an option, but i tried to leave ImageMagick out in order for performance (smaller delay). The image recognition program will take the data from a pipe containing the terminal output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The include file `/usr/include/X11/XWDFile.h` which is part of X11 holds more information. I found this file in rpm `xorg-x11-proto-devel` on my system. In particular, the `HeaderSize` which your link says is always 40 is incorrect. The header file says *header_size = SIZEOF(XWDheader) + length of null-terminated window name*. Further useful comments in the file are

> Null-terminated window name follows the above structure.
>    Next comes XWDColor structures, at offset XWDFileHeader.header_size in
>    the file.  XWDFileHeader.ncolors tells how many XWDColor structures
>    there are.

Here's a bit of python to read the start of an xwd file and print some of this information. It calculates the offset to the first image pixels:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, struct

XWDColorlen = 4*3*2+2*1
MSBFirst = 1

class Xwd:
    def __init__(self,data):
        (self.header_size,
        self.file_version,
        self.pixmap_format,
        self.pixmap_depth,
        self.pixmap_width,
        self.pixmap_height,
        self.xoffset,
        self.byte_order,
        self.bitmap_unit,
        self.bitmap_bit_order,
        self.bitmap_pad,
        self.bits_per_pixel,
        self.bytes_per_line,
        self.visual_class,
        self.red_mask,
        self.green_mask,
        self.blue_mask,
        self.bits_per_rgb,
        self.colormap_entries,
        self.ncolors,
        self.window_width,
        self.window_height,
        self.window_x,
        self.window_y,
        self.window_bdrwidth) = struct.unpack(">25I",data[:100])

f = file(sys.argv[1])
data = f.read()
xwd = Xwd(data)
print("header_size %d  ncolors %d" % (xwd.header_size, xwd.ncolors))

offset = xwd.header_size+xwd.ncolors*XWDColorlen
print("offset %d 0x%x" % (offset,offset))
print("bits_per_pixel %d" % xwd.bits_per_pixel)
if xwd.bits_per_pixel==32:
    if xwd.byte_order==MSBFirst:
        fmt = ">I"
    else:
        fmt = "<I"
    for i in range(20):
        print("%08x" % struct.unpack(fmt,data[offset:offset+4]))
        offset += 4
```

Applied to the data example you provided, it says

```
header_size 124  ncolors 256
offset 6780 0x1a7c
bits_per_pixel 32
```

I see there is also a [perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::XWD) pod to investigate xwd images.